Mapping array column to dynamic in ADX in ADF mapping
I have array of numbers in the dataframe, which i want to map to dynamic column in kusto, But kusto does not support array mapping in ADF yet. Is there any alternative way to achieve the same.
I am expecting some links with procedures to achieve the solution.

Can you provide what you have tried so far? any errors or blockers? and please provide a sample of your input and expected output for better understanding of your issue?

Got the solution, we can achieve the this using derived col;umn in adx, as the support of the same is not yet there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping

You can set the mapping in the copy activity like below to achieve your requirement.
This is the sample starting data containing array:
[
    {
    "id":1,
    "data":[100,101,102,103]
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "data":[1,2,3,4,5]
    }
]

In the sink, give your ADX table and give the mapping like below.

Run the pipeline.
Result table with dynamic column:

If the array is complex, then copy your source data as JSON string to the target table and derive required new columns in the target table using parse_json().
